# Wrapping text in a table cell

Tags: tables

My text alignment of the column headers - "Cumulative Number of Courses Required to be Passed" and "Cumulative Number of Senior Courses Required to be Passed" are clearly wrong. I do recognise that these are unusually long column headers, but I can't think of a more precise term than that at the moment.

[image]

What I'd like is the two column headers to "wrap" more around the "BSc" and "EDP", although not exactly. Perhaps if the cut off is on the word "Courses" (move 'Required' to the second line), that would be nice. Also is it possible to move the EDP columns a bit more to the right, so that it is more closely aligned with the word "Courses" above?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, threeparttable}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Minimum Requirements for Automatic Readmission into the Science Faculty}
\label{table:sci}
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.18\textwidth}*{4}{L{\dimexpr0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}}@{}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Cumulative Number of Courses Required to be Passed} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Cumulative Number of Senior Courses Required to be Passed}  \\
\cmidrule(l){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
& BSc & EDP & BSc & EDP  \\
\midrule
First-year & 2 & 2 & --- & ---  \\
Second-year & 7 & 6 & --- & --- \\
Third-year & 11 & 10 & 3 & 2 \\
Fourth-year & 15 & 14 & 6 & 5 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I made three changes to your table:

1) I added `\centering`

2) I changed the width of the 4 right-side columns to `0.2\textwidth...`, and

3) I placed the headers each in its own `\Longstack`.  This required three additional tweaks in the preamble: add the `stackengine` package; tell the package to use `\#` as the end-of-line, since `tabular` is already using `\\` (note that the latest `stackengine` version 4.00 can use `\\` end-of-line delimiters, even nested inside a `tabular`); and tell the package to set 12pt between baselines of the stack lines, since `tabular` zeroes out the value of `\baselineskip`, which is otherwise the default long-stack gap.  Note that you can give the `\Longstack` a `[l]` or `[r]` optional argument to change it from the default `[c]` alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, threeparttable, stackengine}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\setstackEOL{\#}
\setstackgap{L}{12pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Minimum Requirements for Automatic Readmission into the Science Faculty}
\label{table:sci}
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.18\textwidth}*{4}{L{\dimexpr0.20\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}}@{}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries \Longstack{Cumulative Number\# of Courses Required\# to be Passed}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries \Longstack{Cumulative Number of\# Senior Courses Required\# to be Passed}}  \\
\cmidrule(l){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
& BSc & EDP & BSc & EDP  \\
\midrule
First-year & 2 & 2 & --- & ---  \\
Second-year & 7 & 6 & --- & --- \\
Third-year & 11 & 10 & 3 & 2 \\
Fourth-year & 15 & 14 & 6 & 5 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I noticed that the gaps between "first-year", "second-year", third year etc, are wider, which I guess is what you meant by "tell the package to set 12pt between baselines of the stack lines". It looks  very pleasant - is it possible to have that gap applied to other tables without using the long stack command? I would like to apply it to all my other tables.

Comment: @Chris I don't believe the stacking gap affects anything other than the contents of the `\Longstack`s themselves.  For example, take my MWE, and change the 12pt to 20 pt, and see what happens.  I can't account for perceived changes elsewhere.

Comment: @Chris However, if you did wish to spread out the lines of the complete table, `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}` right before the `threeparttable` would accomplish that.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `c` in `\multicolumn{2}{c}{...` but

```
 \multicolumn{2}{L{\dimexpr0.3\linewidth-8\tabcolsep\relax}}{...
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, threeparttable}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Minimum Requirements for Automatic Readmission into the Science Faculty}
\label{table:sci}
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.18\textwidth}*{4}{L{\dimexpr0.3\linewidth-8\tabcolsep\relax}}@{}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{L{\dimexpr0.4\linewidth-4\tabcolsep\relax}}{\bfseries Cumulative Number of Courses Required to be Passed} &
\multicolumn{2}{L{\dimexpr0.4\linewidth-4\tabcolsep\relax}}{\bfseries Cumulative Number of Senior Courses Required to be Passed}  \\
\cmidrule(l){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
& BSc & EDP & BSc & EDP  \\
\midrule
First-year & 2 & 2 & --- & ---  \\
Second-year & 7 & 6 & --- & --- \\
Third-year & 11 & 10 & 3 & 2 \\
Fourth-year & 15 & 14 & 6 & 5 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for the parsimonious solution @Harish Kumar